# Scrape with PHP and CURL from a Report Viewer

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I would like to work with data from a page that uses report viewer, and the data from this viewer is not found by my CURL code.

[Page URL](http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta%2F2017%2FModulo_AM%2FDetalhamentos%2FUC31-DetContratos-RL&contrato=8678102&periodoSelecionado=0&remessaSelecionada=662325639,668743165,674898703,675479698,682749064,682749296,682752194,684843149,687617053,689543045,689556683,689827842,690502542&orgaoSelecionado=11938&exercicioSelecionado=2017)

The page belongs to this site: [fiscalizandocomtce](http://fiscalizandocomtce.tce.mg.gov.br/)

```
<?php
   $curl = curl_init("http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta%2f2017%2fModulo_AM%2fDetalhamentos%2fUC31-DetContratos-RL&contrato=8678102&periodoSelecionado=0&remessaSelecionada=662325639,668743165,674898703,675479698,682749064,682749296,682752194,684843149,687617053,689543045,689556683,689827842,690502542&orgaoSelecionado=11938&exercicioSelecionado=2017");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

   $page = curl_exec($curl);

   if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
   {
      echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
      exit;
   }

   echo $page;
?>
```

I've tried using simple_html_dom too but it also can not capture the data from the report viewer of the page in question.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta%2f2017%2fModulo_AM%2fDetalhamentos%2fUC31-DetContratos-RL&contrato=8678102&periodoSelecionado=0&remessaSelecionada=662325639,668743165,674898703,675479698,682749064,682749296,682752194,684843149,687617053,689543045,689556683,689827842,690502542&orgaoSelecionado=11938&exercicioSelecionado=2017');

// extract text from HTML
echo $html->plaintext;
?>
```

Is there any other way to do this other than the two I mentioned?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if the url is opening in browser.
secondly it is file_get_contents
and you can use DOMDocument class of PHP to traverse an HTML document and scrape the required data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed to file_get_contents even more so not after the report data. I also do not understand the link being open in my browser, can it interfere?